# WebFlux + RSocket + Spring

Tags: spring-webflux, serversocket, reactor, rsocket, rsocket-java

Can someone tell me or give a ready-made CRUD example using **WebFlux, RScoket and Spring (or SpringBoot)**?

I studied the **RSocket** documentation, **WebFlux**, also wrote my simple examples, but I would like to see a real **CRUD** application using basic methods using **RSocket**.

I'll be very grateful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have maintained [a Spring/RSocket sample project with 4 basic interaction modes of RSocket](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample).

If you only require request/reply case for simple CRUD operations, check the **request and response** mode, and select a transport protocol, TCP or WebSocket.

To implement CRUD operations, just define 4 different routes for them, like define the RESTful APIs using URI, you have to have a good plan for the naming, but in RSocket there are no  HTTP methods to help you to differentiate the same routes.

For example, in the server side, we can declare a `@Controller` to handling messages like this.

```java
@Controller
class ProfileController {

    @MessageMapping("fetch.profile.{name}")
    public Mono<Profile> greet(@DestinationVariable String name) {
    }

    @MessageMapping("create.profile")
    public Mono<Message> greet(@Payload CreateProfileRequest p) {
    }

    @MessageMapping("update.profile.{name}")
    public Mono<Message> greet(@DestinationVariable String name, @Payload UpdateProfileRequest p) {
    }

    @MessageMapping("delete.profile.{name}")
    public Mono<Message> greet(@DestinationVariable String name) {
    }
}
```

In the client side, if it is a Spring Boot application, you can use RSocket `RSocketRequester` to interact with the server side like this.

```java
//fetch a profile by name
requester.route("fetch.profile.hantsy").retrieveMono()

//create a new profile
requester.data(new CreateProfileRequest(...)).route("create.profile").retrieveMono()

//update the existing profile
requester.data(new UpdateProfileRequest(...)).route("update.profile.hantsy").retrieveMono()

//delete a profile
requester.route("delete.profile.hantsy").retrieveMono()
```

Of course, if you just build a service exposed by rsocket protocol, the client can be a rsocket-js project or other languages and frameworks, such as  Angular, React or Android etc.

**Update: I've added a [crud sample](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample/tree/master/crud) in my rsocket sample codes**, and I have published [a post on Medium](https://medium.com/@hantsy/building-a-crud-application-with-rsocket-and-spring-936570c72467).